# minikube's got loads of space, but the pod says no space left on device

Tags: elasticsearch, minikube

I'm trying to run Elasticsearch on minikube on my mac. I'm following the instructions from the Elasticsearch helm repo [here](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/tree/master/elasticsearch/examples/minikube).

I'm starting minikube like this:

```
minikube start --memory 8192 --cpus 4 --disk-size 50000mb
```

which starts fine and indicates the addons listed in the Elasticsearch helm minikube example README are included.

```
  Enabled addons: storage-provisioner, default-storageclass
```

Versions:

```
➜ minikube version
minikube version: v1.23.1
commit: 84d52cd81015effbdd40c632d9de13db91d48d43

➜ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.1", GitCommit:"632ed300f2c34f6d6d15ca4cef3d3c7073412212", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-08-19T15:38:26Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.1", GitCommit:"632ed300f2c34f6d6d15ca4cef3d3c7073412212", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-08-19T15:39:34Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.7", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

I initialise helm with `helm init` and then start elasticsearch with

```
helm install --name elasticsearch elastic/elasticsearch -f values.yaml
```

The values are from here https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/blob/master/elasticsearch/examples/minikube/values.yaml and ask elasticsearch to allow all the pods to run on one node, and request less resources.

I check the elasticsearch pods (there are three) and they've all complained about the same thing:

```
MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "kube-api-access-lxmxc" : write /var/lib/kubelet/pods/5ce1f0e8-6d43-48a0-bac6-55eab6eafc97/volumes/kubernetes.io~projected/kube-api-access-lxmxc/..2021_09_19_06_47_54.897372328/namespace: no space left on device
```

So I log into the minikube VM and navigate into that folder and check the space:

```
➜ minikube ssh
                         _             _
            _         _ ( )           ( )
  ___ ___  (_)  ___  (_)| |/')  _   _ | |_      __
/' _ ` _ `\| |/' _ `\| || , <  ( ) ( )| '_`\  /'__`\
| ( ) ( ) || || ( ) || || |\`\ | (_) || |_) )(  ___/
(_) (_) (_)(_)(_) (_)(_)(_) (_)`\___/'(_,__/'`\____)

$ cd /var/lib/kubelet
$ df -h .
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1        43G  1.5G   39G   4% /var/lib/kubelet
$ df -ih .
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/vda1         25M   13K   25M    1% /var/lib/kubelet
```

which seems fine (though I'm not gonna pretend I ever understood what inodes are).

My problem is that I'm not sure where to look next? I've a pod that says "there's not enough space left on the device" and a device that says "I've got quite a lot of space actually!" and so clearly I'm missing the real problem. But I'm clueless as to what it might actually be!

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes and Minikube did you use?

Comment: using minikube v1.23.1 and k8s 1.22.1. Have updated the question.

Comment: Where exactly do you want to mount your volume? Did you run `make install` command?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak do you mean using this? https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/blob/master/elasticsearch/examples/minikube/Makefile

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak so i ran the make install from the minikube example and it threw up a lot of other issues - I've no clue why running the make install gave me a different set of issues to running the helm install. Turns out the latest helm chart has some bugs, so I reset to an earlier tag and tried again and all good! I didn't learn anything though, other than that helm charts can have bugs. Might delete this question, what do you think?

Comment: Don't remove this question. Look at my explanation in the answer

Comment: I think this is good advice, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Turns out the latest helm chart has some bugs, so I reset to an earlier tag and tried again and all good! I didn't learn anything though, other than that helm charts can have bugs.

Let me try to explain it to you. Generally, you shouldn't use the `latest` tag at all. Helm needs an image and a specific version of it. Look at this example for the [alpine image](https://hub.docker.com/r/alpine/helm):

> The latest docker tag is the latest release version (https://github.com/helm/helm/releases/latest)
>
> Please avoid to use  `latest`  tag for any production deployment. Tag with right version is the proper way, such as  `alpine/helm:3.1.1`

You can also learn a lot from this article: [What's Wrong With The Docker :latest Tag?](https://vsupalov.com/docker-latest-tag/). It is related to docker, but in Helm you use these images. Note what can happen if you use the `latest` tag.

You can also read this [good article](https://jfrog.com/blog/helm-charts-best-practices/). It explain how to proper create helm charts:

> We will use AppVersion as the Docker image tag for our application. That allows us to upgrade Helm chart with new version of Application by just changing value in *Chart.yaml*

```
image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ default .Chart.AppVersion .Values.image.tag }}"
```

Therefore, whenever you use the helm chart, you should make sure what images and in what versions are used. I agree that you can come across images that contain the tag `latest`. You can always change it ;)